# Updating Due Date based on Invoice Date and Vendor

Tags: sql, accounting

I am using DocuWare Workflow Designer (uses SQL) to fill in the due date based on the invoice date and vendor name. In the code below I am trying to have it add 15 days to the invoice date if the vendor is "Hueber - Jones & Coontz" otherwise have the Due Date equal the Invoice Date. The code errors out currently and makes the Due Date equal todays date. I am not able to bring up where in the code its failing. Everything in brackets is references to predefined variables in DocuWare.

SELECT [DW_INVOICE_DATE] FROM [AP] WHERE IF [DW_VENDOR_NAME] = 'HUEBER - JONES & COONTZ' [DW_DUE_DATE] = DATEADD(DD,15,[DW_INVOICE_DATE] ELSE [DW_DUE_DATE] = [DW_INVOICE_DATE]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how DocuWare works, it it's just simple SQL this is the command:

```
UPDATE [AP]
SET [DW_DUE_DATE] = (CASE
                        WHEN [DW_VENDOR_NAME] = 'HUEBER - JONES & COONTZ' THEN DATEADD(DD,15,[DW_INVOICE_DATE]) 
                        ELSE [DW_INVOICE_DATE]
                    END)
```